# Make custom NSSegmentedCell look suppressed

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

I have subclassed `NSSegmentedCell` and override `-(void)drawSegment:(NSInteger)segment inFrame:(NSRect)segmentFrame withView:(NSView *)controlView` and was able to draw the cell contents for both the selected and unselected cell.

However according to Interface Builder, the "Capsule style" is deprecated in Lion and I changed it to the next best thing **"Textured rounded". Mode is "Select Any".
Now both in IB or code I can't seem to make the segment look suppressed when selected.**
I'm taking about the background here, the custom icon itself toggles just fine.

(I'm trying to mimic the exact look of the "View"-Segmented control in Xcode 4).